# Up-to-date OUI database online?

Tags: networking, mac-address

Is there an up-to-date searchable database of [OUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier)s?

Was looking for our "Roomba" vacuum cleaner.  Both `netstat -rn` and `arp -a` showed all our tablets, phones, laptop, router, and two others.  The router, tablets, phones, & laptop were easily identifiable by their OUIs.  One OUI was unknown to four online databases, including the one that Wireshark compiled from "various sources."  Putting in "iRobot" (Roomba manufacturer) in one of them gave a code with too many hex digits, and no obvious way to re-map to six hex digits.

I am looking for another source, because we do have more devices in the house than appeared from those shell commands.

Comment: A GUI app on the same laptop apparently has a better embedded database.  It identified all the devices, including the Roomba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *official* database is hosted by IEEE, the very organization that assigns OUIs to manufacturers in the first place. It can be found at:

- MA-L: http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt
- MA-M: http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui28/mam.txt
- MA-S: http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui36/oui36.txt

with a web-based [search page here](https://regauth.standards.ieee.org/standards-ra-web/pub/view.html) (select "All MAC (MA-L, MA-M, MA-S)" as the database).

Note how there are three databases, because OUIs are **not always 24-bit** (6 digits long) anymore – to avoid running out, IEEE has started assigning 28-bit and even 36-bit prefixes for companies who only need very small ranges. So if a lookup produces a longer prefix than usual, that is **normal.**

(For example, while iRobot has a traditional 24-bit assignment 50-14-79, there's an unrelated but similarly named "Unirobot Corporation" which has a 28-bit assignment 14-4F-D7-A. Yes, that's seven digits, and you do not "re-map" them in any way: it's a seven-digit prefix, period.)

---

If a MAC address does not match any entry in the official IEEE registry,

- If the 2nd digit is 2/6/A/E, it is a private (locally administrated) address. It doesn't correspond to any OUI prefix – it's the MAC equivalent of 192.168.x IP addresses. The address might still be based on the manufacturer's OUI, or it might be completely random (generated on the spot).

  Many phones and laptops nowadays generate random MAC addresses for Wi-Fi connections.
- If the 2nd digit is odd (1/3/5/7/9/B/D/F), it is a group (multicast) address. It doesn't belong to an individual device, but it may show up as a destination address in frames.
- Finally, it's not impossible that a manufacturer might cheap out on OUI registration and just take a random prefix without getting any IEEE authorization.

Answer (score -1):

If you have MacOS, the app IP tracker correctly identifies Roku, Roomba, iPhones, iPads, laptops, Windows, HP Printers.  But that's neither an online source, nor helpful to anyone not running MacOS.  Recent versions of IOS will not help because Apple won't allow IOS apps to read Mac addresses.